# Relabeling of dummy variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

I have the following expression

```
F[p1, p2] a[p1] ** b[p2] - F[p1, p2] a[p2] ** b[p1]
```

where `**` is the [non-commutative multiplication operation in *Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html).

`p1`, `p2` are dummy variables that are integrated or summed over in my example.
Ideally, I'd like *Mathematica* to simplify that expression to

```
(F[p1, p2] - F[p1, p2]) a[p1] ** b[p2]
```

So that the variables in the string `a[pi] ** b[pj]` are sorted according to some rule. In principle I would like to generalize that to monomials of `a` and `b` of arbitrary order.

What I tried to do was a symbolic sum:

```
sum[F[p1, p2] a[p1] ** b[p2] - F[p1, p2] a[p2] ** b[p1], p1, p2]
```

but it doesn't simplify the result. 
Is there a way to do pattern matching so that the dummy variables in my expression are relabeled according to my rule?

Comment: Did you mean to rewrite as `F[p1, p2] (a[p1] ** b[p2] - a[p2] ** b[p1])`? If so, `Factor` will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC). `NCCollect` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
F[p1, p2] a[p1] ** 
    b[p2] - ((F[p1, p2] a[p2] ** b[p1] /. {p1 -> q1, 
       p2 -> q2}) /. {q1 -> p2, q2 -> p1}) // Simplify
```

Have fun!

Comment: My problem is that I want to convert an arbitrary sum of monomials of a's and b's of arbitrary order. Your solution only applies to the particular simplified example I posted (sum of two terms of order two)

Comment: @chubecca One cannot guess of what you have in mind. Post a complete problem with a sum you need.